# Need help connecting 2 plugins, and what is the best way to do it

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to connect 2 plugins to work together. The 2 plugins are WCFM and Fancy Product Designer. For starters I Just need the fancy Product Designer to show up on the add new product area in the admin of WCFM. I don't know if I should create a new plugin or just add to the code.

I tried adding the shortcode for Fancy Product Designer directly into the WCFM plugin and nothing happened.

Comment: I think you should create your own plugin or theme in which you will call your two plugins. So that, they can be updated at any moment without losing your custom code.